# Cannot share Arc variables when spawning threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, ownership

I have the following struct to represent the server object:

```
pub struct Server {
    client_managers: Arc<ClientManager>,
    listener: Option<TcpListener>,
}
```

Here is the code that receives a client's connection and handles it in a new thread:

```
fn serve(&self) {
    for stream in self.listener.as_ref().unwrap().incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                let client_manager = &mut self.client_managers.clone();
                // let client_manager = Arc.new(self.client_managers);
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    client_manager.do_something();

                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("connection error: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error when compiling:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> server/src/server.rs:37:47
   |
37 |                       let client_manager = &mut self.client_managers.clone();
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
38 |                       // let client_manager = Arc.new(self.client_managers);
39 | /                     thread::spawn(move || {
40 | |                         client_manager.nothing();
41 | |                     });
   | |______________________- argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
42 |                   }
   |                   - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

I understood why this error happened. My question is:

1) I use Arc by following some tutorials online. ([Example](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-use-self-while-spawning-a-thread-from-method/8282/4)) But why do their examples work but not mine?

2) How can I fix this error in my situation? (I still want to share the object `client_manager`).

Comment: Please update your question to contain a [mre]. When I tried debugging this I just got a bunch of error messages about missing types, and I didn't know how to fix them all, so I gave up. But I'm guessing it's the `&mut` -- why is that there? I would just write `let client_manager = self.client_managers.clone();` It's an `Arc`, so it's already a reference; there seems no point in making another one.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks. your recommendation works and I understood after reading Rust documentation more carefully. I promise I will deliver workable code next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thread::spawn` takes a closure that is `'static`, meaning that it cannot borrow data from outside the thread. However, this line will clone the `Arc` and borrow it, and passing the borrowed reference into the thread:

```rust
let client_manager = &mut self.client_managers.clone();
thread::spawn(move || {
    client_manager.do_something();
//  ^-- client_manager is a `&mut Arc<_>` borrowed from outside the thread
});
```

Instead, what you want is to just clone the `Arc`, not borrow it in any way before its passed into the thread:

```rust
let client_manager = self.client_managers.clone();
thread::spawn(move || {
    client_manager.do_something();
//  ^-- client_manager is a `Arc<_>` owned by the new thread
});
```

The `Arc` has shared ownership over the value, so it is only destroyed once all `Arc` pointers referring to it falls out of scope, even across threads.